# Is there any way to edit just the track data of an AVI file, like mkvpropedit does with MKV files?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, avi

I am trying to swap the order of 2 audio tracks of an AVI file using `ffmpeg`.

```
ffmpeg -i "infile.avi" -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -map 0:1 -c copy "outfile.avi"
```

This works but the file is being re-encoded, not copied. It takes much longer than a straight copy to finish and the resulting file is larger than the original.

Is there any way to edit just the track data of an AVI file, like mkvpropedit does with MKV files? Command line tool preferred.

```
General
Complete name                            : infile.avi
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
File size                                : 451 MiB
Duration                                 : 43mn 11s
Overall bit rate                         : 1 460 Kbps
Writing application                      : VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.2 (build 2540/release)
Writing library                          : VirtualDubMod build 2540/release

Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : MPEG-4 Visual
Format profile                           : Advanced Simple@L5
Format settings, BVOP                    : 3
Format settings, QPel                    : No
Format settings, GMC                     : No warppoints
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default (MPEG)
Muxing mode                              : Packed bitstream
Codec ID                                 : XVID
Codec ID/Hint                            : XviD
Duration                                 : 43mn 11s
Bit rate                                 : 1 190 Kbps
Width                                    : 656 pixels
Height                                   : 368 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 23.976 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.206
Stream size                              : 367 MiB (82%)
Writing library                          : XviD 1.2.1 (UTC 2008-12-04)

Audio #1
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Codec ID                                 : 55
Codec ID/Hint                            : MP3
Duration                                 : 43mn 11s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel count                            : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 39.5 MiB (9%)
Alignment                                : Aligned on interleaves
Interleave, duration                     : 42 ms (1.00 video frame)
Interleave, preload duration             : 504 ms
Writing library                          : LAME3.98r
Encoding settings                        : -m s -V 4 -q 2 -lowpass 17 -b 128

Audio #2
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Codec ID                                 : 55
Codec ID/Hint                            : MP3
Duration                                 : 43mn 11s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel count                            : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 39.5 MiB (9%)
Alignment                                : Aligned on interleaves
Interleave, duration                     : 42 ms (1.00 video frame)
Interleave, preload duration             : 504 ms
Writing library                          : LAME3.98r
Encoding settings                        : -m s -V 4 -q 2 -lowpass 17 -b 128
```

---

```
$ ffmpeg -i "infile.avi" -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -map 0:1 -c copy "outfile.avi"
ffmpeg version 3.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.1.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libsnappy --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfaac --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libssh --enable-libspeex --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-openssl --enable-libopus --enable-frei0r --enable-libcaca --enable-libsoxr --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx265 --enable-libwebp --enable-libbs2b --enable-librubberband --enable-libopenh264 --disable-lzma --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/1.5.2_1/include/openjpeg-1.5 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, avi, from 'infile.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.2 (build 2540/release)
  Duration: 00:44:03.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1434 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 656x368 [SAR 1:1 DAR 41:23], 1164 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
[avi @ 0x7f826b03d200] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
    Last message repeated 2 times
Output #0, avi, to 'outfile.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf57.41.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 656x368 [SAR 1:1 DAR 41:23], q=2-31, 1164 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[avi @ 0x7f826b03d200] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
frame=63371 fps=1830 q=-1.0 Lsize=  465060kB time=00:44:03.10 bitrate=1441.4kbits/s speed=76.3x    
video:375760kB audio:82597kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.462486%
```

infile.avi 474 MB

outfile.avi 476.2 MB

Comment: ffmpeg should be copying the streams, not re-encoding it. Show the console output of the command.

Comment: OK, I added it to the question since it is too long for a comment.

Comment: It is copying, not re-encoding. And looks like it takes about 35 seconds, which is because it has to reconstruct all streams in the new AVI. You're going to be very disappointed with the time taken if you actually re-encoded this file.

Comment: OK, it does say 'copy' for all streams and it takes 34.6 sec. Re-encoding would take longer for a file this size. In fact it did:
 `ffmpeg -i "infile.avi" -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -map 0:1 "outfile.avi"`

`275.5 sec. = 4.6 min.`
`outfile.avi 165.2 MB (garbage quality)`

Same output file size:
 `ffmpeg -i "infile.avi" -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -map 0:1 -c:v mpeg4 -vtag xvid -qscale:v 3 -c:a copy "outfile.qscale_3.avi"`

`77 sec.`
`outfile.avi 475.6 MB`

But still, a tool like `mkvpropedit` takes a second to edit just the header data to do the same thing. Is that possible with the AVI container?

Comment: Not that I know of. In any case, you don't want to edit the header data. You wish to swap tracks. This is different than setting default or enabled flag for tracks, what MKV allows.

Comment: Actually I DO want to edit the header data TO swap the tracks, just as `mkvpropedit` does. `mkvpropedit` swaps the default audio tracks by setting flags, in place. There must be a simple way to do the same thing with an AVI. At least I'm hoping there is. It seems that `ffmpeg` is just reordering the physical location of the tracks. This is time consuming and resource-intensive, especially for a directory full of files.